# How to Add Class on Checked Input Emelent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In my Scenario I need to add css Class to checked input Elements.

I am getting checked Elements with selected myClass:

```
<input #input class="input-class package_box" name="{{ box.id }}" type="checkbox" value="{{ box.date }}"/>

    let a = $('.package_box:input:checked');
    console.log(a); // it consoles some Native details
```

Now I want to add border on each Checked Elements.

I tried:

```
$('.package_box:input:checked').addClass('addBorder')`; // didn't work
let a = $('.package_box:input:checked'); 
a.map((el) => {
  el.classList.push('addBorder'); // also not working
});
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity; Why do you need to add a class? You can use the checked state in css to update the style when the checkbox is checked.. Or do you need the css class on a parent item to modify the styles of other elements?

Comment: can you please add your HTML, that would help addressing your issue.

Comment: `$('.package_box:input:checked').addClass('addBorder')` this should work fine. Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the issue happening.

Comment: For Curiosity: this is an Angular project with jquery in it ( ex developer did it). and he did some blunders. Now i just want to fix this. i am getting array of elements with checked and i want to add some css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it:

```
let a  = $('.package_box:input:checked');
   a.each(function (t) {
   console.log(a, t);
   $(a).next().addClass('bliking'); // next() func is to get next sibling element.
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
    .addBorder {
        outline: 10px solid #c00;
    }

</style>
<input id="test" class="mycheckbox" name="test" type="checkbox" > Check this </input>

<script>

$(function() {

          $('.mycheckbox').change(function() {


            if ($('.mycheckbox').is(':checked')) {
                console.log("checked");
                $('#test').addClass('addBorder');
            }else{
                $('#test').removeClass('addBorder');
            }
        });

});
</script>
```

Copy and paste above code in your editor and save it into test.html file and run on browser and click on checkbox addBorder class added on the checkbox. Hope it helps.

Comment: Requirement is not as your answer. Thanks.